# Obtener columnas de un query con jdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, base-de-datos, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

tengo un problema y necesito ayuda.

El problema es que estoy tratando de obtener el resultado de un query mediante jdbctemplate y mapear ese resultado en mi clase File.

```
Clase File:
@Entity
@Table(name = "UZTFILE", schema = "UTIC")
public class File implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING1")
    private String texto1;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING2")
    private String texto2;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING3")
    private String texto3;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING4")
    private String texto4;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING5")
    private String texto5;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING6")
    private String texto6;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING7")
    private String texto7;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING8")
    private String texto8;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING9")
    private String texto9;

    @Column(name = "UZTFILE_STRING10")
    private String texto10;

--getters and setters y constructores---
```

Query que estoy ejecutando:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
//Query a ejecutar
String query ="SELECT UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING1 AS INSTRUCCIONDECOBRO, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING2 AS CONTRAPARTIDA, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING3 AS MONEDA, UZF1.UZTFILE_NUMBER2 as VALOR, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING4 AS FORMADECOBRO, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING5 AS TIPOCUENTA, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING6 AS NROCUENTA, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING7 AS REFERENCIA, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING8 AS TIPOIDENTIFICACION, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING9 AS NROIDENTIFICACION, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING10  as NOMBRES FROM UZTFILE UZF1";

//Ejecucion del query
    files = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(File.class));
```

Al ejecutar el query no me da error, todo es correcto pero al mostrar los resultado las columnas me salen nulas y el error se debe xq el query que estoy utilizando emplea alias y el alias no coinciden con el nombre de las propiedades de la clase File.

y Aquí viene mi problema o consulta, ya que no puedo cambiar el nombre de las propiedades de mi clase y tampoco puedo quitar los alias del query, ya que se utilizan diferentes querys y cada querys utilizan diferentes alias.
por ejemplo:

```
String query1= "SELECT UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING1 AS INSTRUCCIONDECOBRO FROM UZTFILE WHERE "condicion"";
//Query 2
String query2= "SELECT UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING1 AS NOMBRES FROM UZTFILE Where "condicion";
```

Hay alguna forma de obtener los resultados ya que no puedo modificar las propiedades de mi clase ni los querys?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar otro método, por ejemplo `queryForRowSet()` en lugar de `query()`, el método devuelve un `RowSet` que puede ser iterado.

Ejecutando la consulta:

```
SqlRowSet rowSet = queryForRowSet("query");
```

LLenando una lista de objetos File:

```
List<File> lista = new ArrayList<>();

// iterar el rowset
while(rowSet.next()){
   
    File f = new File();
    
    // establecer el valor de la propiedad en el objeto file
    // hay varios métodos según el tipo de dato
    // getInt, getDouble, etc
    // en este ejemplo se usa getNString que es para campos cadena
    // al final hay un en enlace a la documentación para consultar
    // todos los métodos disponibles
    f.setPropiedadX(rowSet.getNString("nombreDeLaColumna"))


    lista.add(f);
}
```

Lista de métodos de `SqlRowSet` [Documentanción SqlRowSet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/rowset/SqlRowSet.html)